# Today Extension Widget Use TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with an app using tableviewcontroller. I got an error discribed below.

- I want to use table-view in widget , first i delete the hello world label and drag two object table-view  table-view-cell, new a uitableviewcontroller file to control storyboard,but it's fail.
  [complete image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6poH.jpg)

> bottom window have message (Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 43784: (null)) and issue (MainInterface.storyboard: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.)

*after i drag a new uitableviewcontroller set class run, but it's fail again.*

Comment: Use the default `TodayViewController` file but set the superclass to `UITableViewController` and connect datasource and delegate in Interface Builder.

Comment: I tried to set it , but feels nothing to change and one more crash in thread 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use default TodayViewController, and user your TableViewController be subViewController of TodayViewController. It may help you.